# How to import xml files in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm porting a Spring application to Spring Boot. I'd like to be able to configure Spring Security using xml so I can use my old config files. (I've tried using Java config and it doesn't work).

How do I get Spring Boot to pick up the xml configuration? Spring does not see to have any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@ImportResource`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:<name>.xml")
public class Config {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
   }  
}
```

Refer to these links for proper understanding :

1. **[@ImportResource - Java Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)**
2. **[A well defined example on @ImportResource](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-xml-configuration-example)**

Answer (score 1):

You can import xml configuration using [`org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation. in one of the configuration class which is annotated with `@Configuration` do the following.

If your security config is named `security-config.xml` at the root of the classpath then add the like below.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:security-config.xml"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to import your old xml file ? The best thing about spring-boot is that you don't need to use your old file and you can rewrite it in [java](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html)